# Show that the categorial union of abelian subgroups is the generated union.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I'm required to show that the categorical union in the abelian groups category can be described as the generated union. That is, for $G$ abelian and $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that $G_i \le G$, for every $i \in I$, the subgroup $X := \langle \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i \rangle$ is the categorical union.

The first condition is quite easy. But I'm a little bit confused with the Universal Property of the Catogorical Union. Here is what I've done:

Let $u_i: G_i \to G$ be the inclusions and $u: X \to G$ be also the inclusion. Let's suppose there is some $\mu: A' \to A$, where $A$ is abelian and $\mu$ is monomorphism, such that,

$$f \circ u_i = \mu \circ f_i', \quad \forall i \in I$$

I want to show that we can find $f': X \to A'$ such that $f \circ u = \mu \circ f'$.

I'm not pretty sure on how to define this group morphism, but here is my candidate:

$$
    f'(x) = 
        \left\{ 
            \begin{array}{lc} 
                f_j'(x) & x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i \\
                ??? & x \in X \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i\\
            \end{array} 
        \right.
    $$

If $x \in G_j$ for some $j \in I$, we have that
$$(f \circ u)(x) = (f \circ u_j)(x) = (\mu \circ f'_j)(x) = (\mu \circ f')(x)$$

If $x \in X \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i$, since $X$ is abelian and $I$ could be an infinitely index set, we can express $x$ as follows:

$$x = x_1^{\alpha_1} x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n} \cdots, \quad x_i \in G_i, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Thus,

\begin{align*}
   (f \circ u)(x) & = (f \circ u)(x_1^{\alpha_1} x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots)\\
   & = f(u(x_1^{\alpha_1})) f(u(x_2^{\alpha_2})) \cdots\\
   & = f(u_1(x_1^{\alpha_1})) f(u_2(x_2^{\alpha_2})) \cdots\\
   & = \mu(f_1'(x_1^{\alpha_1})) \mu(f_2'(x_2^{\alpha_2})) \cdots\\
   & = \mu(f_1'(x_1^{\alpha_1}) f_2'(x_2^{\alpha_2}) \cdots )\\
\end{align*}

This means that for $x \in X \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i$ and given the natural complete factorization of $x$, I should define

$$f'(x) = f_1'(x_1^{\alpha_1}) f_2'(x_2^{\alpha_2}) \cdots$$

Hence,

\begin{align*}
   (f \circ u)(x) & = \mu(f_1'(x_1^{\alpha_1}) f_2'(x_2^{\alpha_2}) \cdots )\\
   & = \mu(f'(x))\\
   & = (\mu \circ f')(x)\\
\end{align*}

Note that for this $f'$, $f'(x) \in A'$ for every $x \in X$, since $f_i': G_i \to A'$. Furthermore, $f'$ is group morphism, since in the worst case, W.L.O.G. we have $y \in G_1$ and $x \in X \setminus \bigcup_{i \in I} G_i$, meaning that

$$f'(y)f'(x) = yf_1'(x_1^{\alpha_1}) f_2'(x_2^{\alpha_2}) \cdots = f_1'(yx_1^{\alpha_1}) f_2'(x_2^{\alpha_2}) \cdots = f'(yx)$$

Does all of this makes sense? Please let me know if I'm committing a mistake.

Comment: Just to check, what definition of categorical union are you using? Supremum in the poset of subobjects?

Comment: @FShrike Yep. Let $\{u_i: A_i \to A\}_{i \in I}$, where every $u_i$ is mono. We define $u: A' \to A$ as the union iff 1) there is $\gamma_i: A_i \to A$ s.t. $u \circ \gamma_i = u_i$, for every $i \in I$ and 2) If $f: A \to B$ is morphism and there is $f_i': A_i \to B'$ such that $\mu \circ f_i' = f \circ u_i$, for every $i \in I$, where $\mu: B' \to B$ is subobject. Then, $\mu \circ f' = f \circ u$, for some $f': A' \to B'$.